# Pretérito perfeito composto e estados contínuos: “ela tem estado grávida”?

Tags: significado, diferenças, tempo-verbal

Basicamente, **quando é que o pretérito perfeito composto (PPC) se aplica a estados contínuos, como o “o Beto *tem estado* gripado”**?

O PPC indica por excelência ações que se vêm repetindo até ao passado recente, podendo continuar no presente. Exemplos da *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian (tomo II, 2013, p. 1258):

> O João *tem visitado* a avó.
>   A Clara *tem feito* os trabalhos de casa.
>   O Cristiano Ronaldo *tem marcado* muitos golos.

Mas pode também aplicar-se a estados contínuos. Pode “representar uma única situação que se prolonga no tempo”, diz a *Gramática* (p. 1261), dando como exemplos:

> O João *tem estado* doente.
>   Nos últimos cinco anos, o Pedro  *tem morado* em Lisboa.

Por outro lado parece-me claro que o PPC não se aplica a todos os estados contínuos. A mim custa-me a aceitar coisas como:

> ??A Ana *tem estado* grávida.
>   ??*Tenho estado* aqui nos Açores há duas semanas.
>   ??*Tenho tido* estes óculos desde 2012.

Para não falar em:

> ???*Tenho sido* doutorado desde 2004.

Em todos estes casos eu usaria o presente do indicativo: “a Ana *está* grávida”, “*estou* aqui nos Açores há duas semanas”, “tenho estes óculos desde 2012”, “*sou* doutorado desde 2004”. No caso da Ana, se quisesse focar explicitamente o passado, como faz o PPC, poderia dizer, “a Ana *está* grávida há algum tempo”. Mesmo no exemplo do Pedro da *Gramática* — “nos últimos cinco anos, o Pedro  *tem morado* em Lisboa” — parece-me mais natural:

> O Pedro *mora* em Lisboa há cinco anos.

No entanto não tenho a certeza que o significado seja exatamente o mesmo. Por outro lado não tenho problema nenhum com:

> O Beto *tem estado* com gripe.
>   *Tenho estado* aqui à tua espera há montes de tempo. Estava a ver que não aparecias.
>   Este ano *tem sido* seco.

**Então a pergunta é:**

1. Quais são os fatores que permitem/impedem, ou facilitam/dificultam, a aplicação do PPC a estados contínuos?
2. Quando o PPC é substituído pelo presente do indicativo — “nos últimos cinco anos, o Pedro tem morado” versus “o Pedro mora há cinco anos” — o significado mantém-se ou altera-se de algum modo?

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Quais são os fatores que permitem/impedem, ou facilitam/dificultam, a aplicação do PPC a estados contínuos?

Eu diria que o sentido mais forte do pretérito perfeito composto é de fato a *repetição* e que, quando usado na situação contínua, ele confere portanto um certo caráter de *insistência* à continuidade.

Por isso, ao meus ouvidos, dentre as duas frases:

> Tem morado em Lisboa.
>   Tem morado no esgoto.

a primeira soa um pouco estranha, mas a segunda não - porque esta última situação de fato parece exigir intenção ou esforço para ser mantida, conforme o sentido que o PPC em algum grau confere.

E por isso que perturbam exemplos como:

> "A Ana *tem estado* grávida.", "*Tenho tido* estes óculos desde 2012.", "*Tenho sido* doutorado desde 2004.", etc.,

porque parece se sugerir que se refere a estados ativamente mantidos, o que normalmente não é o caso nesses exemplos.

Ao mesmo tempo, de maneira relacionada (uma vez que algo que exige esforço para ser mantido tende a durar menos), o PPC pode lembrar da impermanência das coisas:

> O João *tem visitado* a avó.  --  *Não sei se continuará.*
>   A Clara *tem feito* os trabalhos de casa.   --  *Antes não o fazia.*
>   O João *tem estado* doente.  --  *Espero que melhore logo.*
>   Farias *tem fotografado* flores.  --  *Pode mudar de tema.*

Então, respondendo à questão

> 2. Quando o PPC é substituído pelo presente do indicativo — “nos últimos cinco anos, o Pedro tem morado” versus “o Pedro mora há cinco anos” — o significado mantém-se ou altera-se de algum modo?

eu diria que, enquanto o presente do indicativo é neutro, o PPC pode sutilmente aludir ao caráter possivelmente temporário da residência de Pedro.

Comment: Também tenho a impressão que *mora há [x tempo]* é mais definitivo que *tem morado*, mas uma impressão baseada num exemplo não faz teoria. Quanto ao resto, fiquei confuso: num lado dizes que o PPC aplicado a estados contínuos insiste na continuidade, noutro, que indica impermanência, que é um bocado o oposto...

Comment: @Jacinto Tentei explicitar a conexão adicionando o comentário: "*uma vez que algo que exige esforço para ser mantido tende a durar menos*". A ideia é que estados que exigem esforço para serem mantidos não são os mais naturais ou estáveis e, portanto, são mais fáceis de se alterarem. Por exemplo, alguém poderia afirmar "Como 1500 cal/dia." e "Tenho comido apenas 200 cal/dia.", mas seria difícil de acreditar num adulto que afirmasse "Como apenas 200 cal/dia." (não é um estado que se possa manter).

Comment: Em outras palavras: uma escolha de palavras que sugere esforço para manter um estado lembra da impermanência desse estado que, afinal, se altera na ausência do esforço.